# What are the basic difference between IDE and Interpreter?

Tags: python

I know Interpreter translate programming language to machine language. But I can'
t distinguish between IDE and Interpreter. I mean when I run a code how do they work, what are their purpose?

Comment: An IDE bundles a text editor with a number of tools into an *Integrated Development Environment*. An interpreter in some form or another may be among those tools.

Comment: You call interpreter as `python my_file.py`. IDE behind the scenes does exactly the same , but you only need to press some button

Comment: The IDE is fancy code editor. It has syntax highlighting, search tools, refactoring, analysis, etc.

Answer (score -1):

IDE (Integrated Development Environment) is a GUI tool that makes it easier to code, but does the same job as working from the terminal screen. For instance when you run python code by pressing shift+F10 in pycharm, it executes python3 your_file.py command automatically. Even plain text editor can be used to write code.

Interpreter is the core file which understands your text and transforms it to machine language.